# Phoenix mix - compile can't find dependency of dependency

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

In my Phoenix app, I am having an issue where `mix` seems to be unable to find the dependencies of one of my dependencies... let me break it down...

I added a dep called `opentok` to `mix.exs` and ran `mix deps.get` - it's all good, was installed, added to `mix.lock`, etc.  However, when I ran `mix deps.compile`, I got several messages relating to dependencies of the dependency... for example:

```
DEP    jwt
mv: /Users/user/projects/phoenix_app/deps/opentok/deps/jwt/ebin/jwt.app: No such file or directory
```

But I must respectfully disagree, the file is definitely there, I'm looking right at it, it came in with the dep with `deps.get`.

Ok so obviously, there's more to this process than I understand.  What step am I missing here?  How can I get `mix` to find the file that I know is there?

For what it's worth, I tried the whole thing totally fresh - ran `mix deps.unlock --all`, `mix deps.clean --all`, `mix deps.get`, `mix deps.compile`, still the same thing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hex registry for opentok seems to be broken. If you still need to use it, try the github version in your mix.exs:

```
{:opentok, github: "eyrmedical/opentok"}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure if this is exactly my problem, but it's good to know.